# How to use pp_write_error from mirage-channel

Tags: ocaml, mirage

I'm using [mirage-channel](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-channel) and Channel.flush returns a `(unit, Channel.write_error) Result.result`. I can't figure out how to convert that Channel.write_error to a string, seems like there is a `pp_write_error` but I just don't get how to use it.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like it uses [the `fmt` library](http://erratique.ch/software/fmt/doc/Fmt.html#nameconv) (via `mirage-flow`) and that you're supposed to use `Fmt.pf` with a [formatting string](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/format.html) similarly to how you'd use `printf`, which involves a bit of type trickery and compiler magic to work. It would have been nice if the documentation had even just one example to aid in understanding the types and their use.

Comment: Fiddled a lot with it and got something that seems to compile : `| Error e -> Lwt.return_error (Fmt.strf "%a" Channel.pp_write_error e)`. Does that look okay ? I couldn't figure out Fmt.pf, it wants a Formatter and I have no idea what to use, strf doesn't

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that seems about like how I'd expect it to look. `strf` seems like the analog of `sprintf`, while `pf` is more like `fprintf` which'll print to a given channel.

Comment: Great, thanks ! I'll try to force some tcp errors at some point to test it out properly, but for now it'll do